# Firefox printing variables

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, printing, print-css

I have a really simple page generating a ticket. It has an img behind the user's name + ticket code.
Everything is displaying correctly, but firefox doesn't print these names at all. Any ideas?

EDIT: I have added all the code I have there. Not sure what I can add more.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>    
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>FN Ticket</title>
        <style>
            body{
                overflow:scroll;
                text-align:center;
            }
            .box{
               /* background-image: url('/images/Karolina_GFX/2bilet.jpg');*/
                background-repeat: no-repeat;
                height:1200px;
                width:848px;
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
            }
            .data{
                position:relative; bottom:820px;
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
            }
            #imie{
               display:inline; 
               font-size:36px;
               color:#4D4949;
            }
            #nazwisko{
               display:inline;
               font-size:36px;
               color:#4D4949;
            }
            #kod{
               font-size:36px;
               color:#4D4949;
            }
            .print{
                margin-left:auto;
                margin-right:auto;
                margin-top:20px;
                margin-bottom:20px;
                padding:5px;
            }

     @media print {
         .print{
             display:none;
         }
    }

        </style>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button class='print'>WYDRUKUJ</button>
        <div class='box'>
            <image src='/images/Karolina_GFX/2bilet.jpg'>
            <div class='data'>
            <p id='imie'><?php echo $ticketData[0]->f_name; ?> </p>
            <p id='nazwisko'><?php echo $ticketData[0]->f_surname; ?></p>

            <p id='kod'>Kod: <?php echo $ticketData[0]->f_code; ?></p>
        </div>


            <script>
            $('.print').on('click', function(){
                print();
            });
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is the code of `print` function ?

Comment: Only Firefox behaves like this? Did you check in other browsers?

Comment: @MysterX added it above, sorry for that

Comment: @EduardoGalván chrome works fine

Comment: Where is the background img? <img> tag is not actually a backgrond but if there is **really** a background image (and that is what you miss), notice that most browsers stylesheets for media=print hide background images by default. If this is the case, you need to override those css rules.

Comment: You should really add some more details and a plunker. This works for me in Firefox.

Comment: When you say print, do you mean print to paper? using window.print() ?

Comment: Yes, I mean printing it on paper. I have edited my post and now it contains all the code that i have

Comment: Then you should use `window.print()` documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/print)

Comment: Hi @divHelper11 Try adding the code as well as the images it references to https://plnkr.co then adding a link.

Comment: @bitifet Actually I have replaced `background` with `<img>` because it wasnt visible while printing without checking this option in printing dialog box.

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.print()` as this is a browser function

[Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Window/print)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is you need to set it up in the Mozilla Firefox print dialog. You should inform users of that, as I don't know of any way to activate it from javascript.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can simply use window.print() function which will do job for you.

`https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print`

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed A similar problem by attaching the `print` to `onClick` event on the button directly. Try using code below:

```
onclick='printMe()'
```

When your function should contain:

```
window.print();
```

Comment: Not necessary. onclick="window.print()", or onclick="javascript:window.print()" will do the job in every major browser.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like few recent firefox updates fixed this issue.